# Migrating from Parse to back{4}app, new parse SDK is throwing errors Parse/PFNullability.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, swift2, xcode7, back4app

I have migrated from Parse to back{4}app. I have updated the parse SDK and have been deleting and retrying frameworks for the past two days to no avail. When I go to run the app Xcode returns two errors. 'Parse/PFNullability.h' file not found
and 'failed to import bridging header'. The app works perfectly before I add the new Parse SDK and new code for parse client configuration. But as soon as I update the Parse SDK it returns the errors. I have deleted paths, frameworks a number of times. Updated Xcode to the latest version.
I have read all the relevant posts and none of the answers have worked for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. SDKs and Parse API are up to date.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the errors.]

Comment: You are using cocoapods in your project?

Comment: Hi Ran, no I'm not using cocoapods.

Comment: I am using cocoapods and added parse to my both swift and objective c projects and it works without any issue .. There is a chance for you to use cocoapods ?

Comment: Ya I could I suppose, I've never used cocoapods before. I will give it ago thanks Ran, if I'm successful I'll let you know.

Comment: if you need any help with it i can create some project and upload it to github

Comment: Hey Ran ya I used cocoapods and it was the same errors being called? From what I can find online it seems to just bug, all the different solutions are all "This worked for some but not others". I'm currently going through a list of these and so far none have worked for me. Solutions such as deleting podfile.lock and redoing pod install, deleting the modules folders from the facebook frameworks (a suggestion from facebook themselves) etc. Nothing works as of yet and I've started from scratch a load of times as well.

Answer (score 1):

First check the Facebook and Parse SDK versions, if you need you can update your [Facebook parse version](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseFacebookUtils-iOS/releases)
and update your [Parse SDK version](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/releases/tag/1.14.2).

Comment: Ya I have checked both and downloaded the most up to date, I've also done the same with cocoapods still throws the same errors.